# Ensuring groupby output type

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
foo = pd.DataFrame(dict(letter=['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
                 number=[1,1,2,2,3,np.nan, np.nan,4]))
grouped = foo.groupby(foo.number)
print grouped['letter'].transform(lambda x: sum(x=='a'))

Out[18]: 
0    2
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    b
6    a
7    0
```

Instead of showing `1` on rows `5` and `6`, `'a'`, and `'b'` are shown, presumably because the groupby was indexed on a `np.nan` value. Is there any way to stop this from happening, without replacing `nan` values with some dummy variable? Also - why does this happen?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like groups grouped by `nan` are excluded (see `print grouped.groups`).  Also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pandas docs explain this here:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

NAN's are excluded this is consistent with R.

Earlier versions of Pandas did include them but they have since been removed.

Comment: Thanks. So, not possibly without dummy variables.