# Pandas groupby aggregate not giving the expected number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that I group by several columns, some of which contain null values:

```
>>> gp = df.groupby(columns)
```

I expect there to be ~1000 distinct groups, and this is what I get using `len()`:

```
>>> len(gp)
1000
```

However, when I apply an aggregate function, I only get ~50 rows back!

```
>>> gp.mean().shape[0]
50
```

Any ideas? Is this because the columns which I use for aggregating contain null values? Is there a way to force pandas to treat null values as any other value, and produce the output that you would get using SQL `GROUP BY` and `AVG?`

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18431417/3453737). In short, use `fillna` to replace the value and then do the groupby.

Comment: @shawnheide Yup, thanks! I had even upvoted that post before. However, this behavious is **very** unintuitive for me. I would much rather call `df = df.dropna(subset=columns)` when I want to exclude nulls than call `df.loc[:, columns] = df[columns].fillna('')` before groupby and `df.loc[:, columns] = df[columns].replace('', np.nan)` after, if I want to include them....