# Pandas fillna using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to impute/fill values using rows with similar columns' values.

For example, I have this dataframe:

```
one | two | three
1      1     10
1      1     nan
1      1     nan
1      2     nan
1      2     20
1      2     nan
1      3     nan
1      3     nan
```

I wanted to using the keys of column `one` and `two` which is similar and if column `three` is not entirely nan then impute the existing value from a row of similar keys with value in column '3'.

Here is my desired result:

```
one | two | three
1      1     10
1      1     10
1      1     10
1      2     20
1      2     20
1      2     20
1      3     nan
1      3     nan
```

You can see that keys 1 and 3 do not contain any value because the existing value does not exists.

I have tried using `groupby`+`fillna()`:

```
df['three'] = df.groupby(['one','two'])['three'].fillna()
```

which gave me an error.

I have tried forward fill which give me rather strange result where it forward fill the column 2 instead. I am using this code for forward fill.

```
df['three'] = df.groupby(['one','two'], sort=False)['three'].ffill()
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If only one non NaN value per group use `ffill` (forward filling) and `bfill` (backward filling) per group, so need `apply` with `lambda`:

```
df['three'] = df.groupby(['one','two'], sort=False)['three']
                .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
   one  two  three
0    1    1   10.0
1    1    1   10.0
2    1    1   10.0
3    1    2   20.0
4    1    2   20.0
5    1    2   20.0
6    1    3    NaN
7    1    3    NaN
```

But if multiple value per group and need replace `NaN` by some constant - e.g. `mean` by group:

```
print (df)
   one  two  three
0    1    1   10.0
1    1    1   40.0
2    1    1    NaN
3    1    2    NaN
4    1    2   20.0
5    1    2    NaN
6    1    3    NaN
7    1    3    NaN

df['three'] = df.groupby(['one','two'], sort=False)['three']
                .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
print (df)
   one  two  three
0    1    1   10.0
1    1    1   40.0
2    1    1   25.0
3    1    2   20.0
4    1    2   20.0
5    1    2   20.0
6    1    3    NaN
7    1    3    NaN
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @jezrael: is there any reason that force to use `apply` in your answer? I am asking because I tried direct `ffill` and `bfill` and it returns correct result: `df['three'] = df.groupby(['one', 'two'])['three'].ffill().bfill()`

Comment: @Andy L. It working correct, because last group is only NaN group. If change sample data for first only NaN group (10 to NaN) , your solution failed. Reason is last bfill working not per groups, but per Series returned groupby +ffill.

Comment: ah, I forgot that the `bfill` back-fills the output series from `ffill`, not the `groupby`. Thanks for answers

Comment: May I ask, how can I apply `df['three'] = df.groupby(['one','two'], sort=False)['three'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())` to multiple columns `three, four, five, etc` instead of only `three` which need groupby `one` and `two` and fillna?

Comment: @ahbon - Use `cols = ['three','four','five']` and `df[cols] = df.groupby(['one','two'], sort=False)[cols].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`

Comment: This solution may not work as intended if the grouping columns include `NaN` values. How to fix it? One idea is to 
`df['four'] = df.groupby(['one','two'], sort=False)['three'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())` and then 
`df.loc[df.four.isnull(),'four']=df.three`

Is there a better way?

Comment: @volkang - `This solution may not work as intended if the grouping columns include NaN values` - it means columns `one, two` ? Because if you think `three` it working well, see answer - last group `1,3` - only NaNs per groups ouput is `NaN`s.

Comment: Yes I meant `one` or `two`

Comment: @volkang - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/pandas-groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values)

Comment: I tried adding `dropna=False` in the grouper, but seems not to work. Could you try on this `df` for example? 
`data = {
    'one':  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,np.nan,99],
    'two':  [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,99,np.nan],
    'three':[10,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,20,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,999,888]
}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: @volkang - I guess your pandas version is <1.1, so need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39857303/2901002) solution.

Comment: @jezrael Nope. My pandas version is '1.3.1'. However, I tried changing columns to `string` and use `dropna=False`. With that, it works. Thanks. You wanna add this to your answer to make it more comprehensive?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort data by the column with missing values then groupby and forwardfill:

```
df.sort_values('three', inplace=True)
df['three'] = df.groupby(['one','two'])['three'].ffill()
```