# Pandas fill missing values with groupby

Tags: pandas, fillna

I have a table of various indicators grouped by Date and Code. I am trying to fill missing values with the previous day's data OR if not available - with the next day's data for each Code.

The problem is when I group by 'Code' and 'Date', nothing happens

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-05-01', 'APL', 15951, 303, 49],  
['2019-05-02', 'APL', 16075, 301, 46],  
['2019-05-03', 'APL', np.nan, 300, 45],  
['2019-05-04', 'APL', 15868, 298.8, 33],  
['2019-05-01', 'MSK', 2222, np.nan, np.nan],  
['2019-05-02', 'MSK', 2224, 243, 53],  
['2019-05-03', 'MSK', 2266, 233, 33],  
['2019-05-04', 'MSK', np.nan, 253, 55]],  
columns=['Date', 'Code', 'Price', 'Volume', 'ATM'])
```

Here is what I am trying:

```py
df.groupby(['Code','Date'])['Price','Volume', 'ATM'].fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
df.groupby(['Code']).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

Output:

```
    Code      Date  Price   Volume  ATM
0   APL 2019-05-01  15951.0 303.0   49.0
1   APL 2019-05-02  16075.0 301.0   46.0
2   APL 2019-05-03  16075.0 300.0   45.0
3   APL 2019-05-04  15868.0 298.8   33.0
4   MSK 2019-05-01  2222.0  243.0   53.0
5   MSK 2019-05-02  2224.0  243.0   53.0
6   MSK 2019-05-03  2266.0  233.0   33.0
7   MSK 2019-05-04  2266.0  253.0   55.0
```

If you groupby `['Date', 'Code']`, each day becomes a group and within that group, there will not be any missing values.

Comment: when you chain two functions , you need adding the apply here

Comment: @WeNYoBen how come? I have seen chaining done without apply, many times.

Comment: Does this return `Code` column also?

Comment: @Josmoor98 yes. Ofcourse, as you can see in the output

Comment: Using your solution, the `Code` columns is omitted from the result

Comment: @Josmoor98, it is not. I have ran the code and `Code` is in the output. Did you run the code? :(

Comment: Really, that's odd, for me `Code` is missing. Using pandas `0.22.0` in  a jupyter notebook FYI

Comment: @harvpan edge situation try groupby with id , using without apply `df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'v':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,999,999,999,999]})
`

Comment: thanks @harvpan , moving 'Date' away from groupby was the key!

Comment: @Josmoor98 hmm.. try `df.groupby(['Code'], as_index=False)['Date', 'Price','Volume', 'ATM'].ffill().bfill()`

Comment: Still getting the same issue. I only get your output using `df.groupby(['Code']).ffill().bfill()`. With `['Date', 'Price','Volume', 'ATM']` aren't you slicing on those columns?

Comment: @harvpan: Read this the comment @jerael replied to me on exact issue of chaining `.ffill.bfill` with `groupby`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391128/pandas-fillna-using-groupby/46391144?noredirect=1#comment98276167_46391144

Comment: @WeNYoBen Didn't realize about this. thanks. Updated the answer.

Comment: @AndyL. thanks for collaborative comments. This really clears out why apply is best for chaining

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
df.set_index(['Date', 'Code'], inplace=True)
df['Price'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To apply to specific columns, I use.

```
for col in list_of_cols:  # Replace with your list of column name
    df[col] = df.groupby('Code')[col].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```