# fill nan values with values from another row with common values in two or more columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, fill, fillna

I've a dataframe and some of the values are missing. Luckily there are other rows which share the same attributes and values in other columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ('x','x','y'),
                  'B': (2,2,2),
                  'C':(3, np.nan, 7)})
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 2 | 3 |
| x | 2 | nan |
| y | 2 | 7 |

Is there a fill method to populate the nan value in the 2nd row based on the common attributes of column A and B?
i.e. nan should be filled to 3.

I've got a bigger dataframe so need a way of doing it systematically.

Comment: use `ffill()` method i.e `df['C']=df['C'].ffill()`

Comment: no, that's not what i am after. It needs to reference column A and B (in practice, more columns). forward fill is not what i am after. I could technically have 2nd row and 3rd row swtiched and ffill will give a different result.

Comment: then make use of `groupby()` method...see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391128/pandas-fillna-using-groupby

Comment: yea that might work for me...