# How to fill in the nan values based on prior found values in the pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pandas-groupby, fillna

I have the following example dataframe (normal dataframe has more than 1000 rows)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'P1':['jaap','tim','piet','tim','tim'],
                   'P2':['piet','jaap','jaap','piet','jaap'],
                   'Count1':[2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'Count2':[3, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
print(df)

     P1    P2  Count1  Count2
0  jaap  piet     2.0     3.0
1   tim  jaap     3.0     1.0
2  piet  jaap     NaN     NaN
3   tim  piet     NaN     NaN
4   tim  jaap     NaN     NaN
```

Now I want to find a neat way that fills in the `NaN` values, according to the following rule:

```
The names found in P1 and P2 have to be the same.
```

Thus the nan values found in row number `2` have to be the same as the values in row `0`, only the values have to be swapped since the names are also swapped. The nan values in row `3` should be kept as nan, since the combination of `tim` and `piet` is not found in any prior row. The nan values in row `4` have to be the same as the values in row `1`.
So the desired result is:

```
     P1    P2  Count1  Count2
0  jaap  piet     2.0     3.0
1   tim  jaap     3.0     1.0
2  piet  jaap     3.0     2.0
3   tim  piet     NaN     NaN
4   tim  jaap     3.0     1.0
```

This question is very similar:
[Pandas fillna using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391128/pandas-fillna-using-groupby?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Only if the proposed solution in that article is applied to the question in this post, the result is slightly off:

```
df.groupby(['P1','P2'])[['Count1','Count2']].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method = 'ffill'))
print(df)

             Count1  Count2
  P1   P2                  
0 jaap piet     2.0     3.0
1 tim  jaap     3.0     1.0
2 piet jaap     NaN     NaN
3 tim  piet     NaN     NaN
4 tim  jaap     3.0     1.0
```

As you can see the names `jaap` and `piet` in row `0` changed column in row `2`, thus it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I miss there is some values swapped.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create DataFrame with changed order first in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `rename`, remove rows with missing values and possible duplicates and change original values by [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
d = {'P2':'P1','P1':'P2','Count1':'Count2','Count2':'Count1'}
df1 = (pd.concat([df, df.rename(columns=d)])
         .dropna(subset=['Count1','Count2'])
         .drop_duplicates(['P1','P2']))

df = df.set_index(['P1','P2'])
df1 = df1.set_index(['P1','P2'])

df.update(df1)

df = df.reset_index()
print (df)

     P1    P2  Count1  Count2
0  jaap  piet     2.0     3.0
1   tim  jaap     3.0     1.0
2  piet  jaap     3.0     2.0
3   tim  piet     NaN     NaN
4   tim  jaap     3.0     1.0
```

Comment: Only a small difference. The values in row number 2 have to be vice versa. It should be: Count1 = 3.0 and Count2 = 2.0 . In row 0 Count1 (belonging to jaap) has value 2.0 and Count2 (belonging to piet) has value 3.0.

Comment: @Herwini - Can you check now?

Comment: Row number 2 is correct now. Only the values in row 1 and 4 are now swapped.

Comment: @Herwini - you are right, working for it.

Comment: Thanks! Would be perfect.

Comment: @Herwini - One thing - are alwyas NaN in both columns Count?

Comment: Ether both values are NaN or none are NaN in the count columns. Does that answer you question?

Comment: @Herwini - Can you test now?

Comment: This seems to be working! Thanks for the work.