# How can I copy the value of a previous row, on the same column in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

| Date | Track | Surface | FGrating | HorseId | Last FGrating at Sha Tin, grass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-09-03 | Sha Tin | Grass | 110 | 1736 |  |
| 2017-09-16 | Sha Tin | Grass | 124 | 1736 | 110 |
| 2017-10-14 | Sha Tin | Grass | 118 | 1736 | 124 |
| 2017-11-11 | Sha Tin | Grass | 107 | 1736 | 118 |
| 2018-03-28 | Happy Valley | Grass | 117 | 1736 |  |
| 2018-04-11 | Happy Valley | Grass | 114 | 1736 |  |
| 2018-09-22 | Sha Tin | Grass | 124 | 1736 | 107 |

As you can see, there are spaces for the *Last FGrating at Sha Tin, grass*. These spaces have two causes:

1. There is no last FGrating (the first record);
2. There is a last FGrating for this track, but it was not written when the race for the same horse was on another track (Happy Valley grass, in this table).

So far, I managed to do only the filling part, according to this code:

```
def return_mask_and_text_from_tracks(data, track_no, metric):
    if track_no == 0:  # Sha Tin - grass
        mask = (data.Track == 'Sha Tin') & (data.Surface == 'Grass')
        text = str(metric) + ' at Sha-Tin Grass'
    if track_no == 1:  # Sha Tin - dirt
        mask = (data.Track == 'Sha Tin') & (data.Surface == 'Dirt')
        text = str(metric) + ' at Sha-Tin Dirt'
    if track_no == 2:  # Happy Valley - grass
        mask = (data.Track == 'Happy Valley') & (data.Surface == 'Grass')
        text = str(metric) + ' at Happy Valley Grass'
    return mask, text

def compute_last_fgrating(data, mask=''):
    if len(mask) == 0:
        return data.groupby('HorseId')['FGrating'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1))
    else:
        return data.loc[mask][['HorseId', 'FGrating']].groupby('HorseId')['FGrating'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1))

for i in range(3):
    mask, text = return_mask_and_text_from_tracks(featured_data, i, 'Last FGrating')
    featured_data[text] = compute_last_fgrating(featured_data, mask=mask)
```

I am looking for ways to fill the rightmost column with the following values:

1. 0, when no last FGrating exist (the first record, in this case)
2. The last FGrating on Sha Tin grass on the records where the race was on other tracks, for the same horse.

The final table should look like this:

| Date | Track | Surface | FGrating | HorseId | Last FGrating at Sha Tin, grass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-09-03 | Sha Tin | Grass | 110 | 1736 | 0 (no previous FGrating exists) |
| 2017-09-16 | Sha Tin | Grass | 124 | 1736 | 110 |
| 2017-10-14 | Sha Tin | Grass | 118 | 1736 | 124 |
| 2017-11-11 | Sha Tin | Grass | 107 | 1736 | 118 |
| 2018-03-28 | Happy Valley | Grass | 117 | 1736 | 118 (the lastFGrating on Sha Tin grass at this point) |
| 2018-04-11 | Happy Valley | Grass | 114 | 1736 | 118 |
| 2018-09-22 | Sha Tin | Grass | 124 | 1736 | 107 |

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you please provide us with code, what you made so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you only need

```py
df["Last FGrating at Sha Tin, grass"] = df["Last FGrating at Sha Tin, grass"].fillna(method="ffill").fillna(0)
```

## Explanation

The first `fillna` fill NaN with the latest value available (`method="ffill"`) then you have left only one NaN on your first row and you can fill it with `0`.

Comment: It works fine. How can I extend this method so that I get the same result for every `HorseId` that I have? Right now, it ignores the `HorseId`.

Comment: You could use a `groupby`.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391144/4819376)

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks!