# Replace the empty values in column based on another column Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| Corp | TDS | VVT | SOAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Steam | 3429.0 | 450 |  |
| Steam |  | 1365 |  |
| Bliz | 3425.1 |  | 11 |
| Bliz | 353.3 | 34 |  |
| Tesla |  |  | 18 |
| Tesla | 2243.3 |  | 32 |
| OYV |  | 15 |  |
| OYV |  |  | 16 |

What is the best way to replace emptiness in the columns with the same value from another row if the Corp value is equal?

The result should be like this:

| Corp | TDS | VVT | SOAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Steam | 3429.0 | 450 |  |
| Steam | 3429.0 | 1365 |  |
| Bliz | 3425.1 | 34 | 11 |
| Bliz | 353.3 | 34 | 11 |
| Tesla | 2243.3 |  | 18 |
| Tesla | 2243.3 |  | 32 |
| OYV |  | 15 | 16 |
| OYV |  | 15 | 16 |

Comment: Will there always be two rows per Corp? If that's not the case, how do you handle what to do when you have multiple values in a column to fill another row?

Comment: What if there are to different values in other rows for the same Corp, how do you decide which you take to replace an empty value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas fillna using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391128/pandas-fillna-using-groupby)

Comment: @aaossa now this is always two rows per Corp :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `ffill` and `bfill`:

```
df.groupby('Corp').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

    Corp     TDS     VVT  SOAR
0  Steam  3429.0   450.0   NaN
1  Steam  3429.0  1365.0   NaN
2   Bliz  3425.1    34.0  11.0
3   Bliz   353.3    34.0  11.0
4  Tesla  2243.3     NaN  18.0
5  Tesla  2243.3     NaN  32.0
6    OYV     NaN    15.0  16.0
7    OYV     NaN    15.0  16.0
```

If you have blanks:

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)\
  .groupby('Corp').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```