# How to fill NaN values in 3 columns based on group of values in 2 other columns in Data Frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
data = [
    (1, None, None, None, '2023-01-10'),
    (1, None, None, None, '2023-01-10'),
    (1, 9, 0, 0.55, '2023-01-10'),
    (2, None, None, None, '2023-11-22'),
    (2, 88, 1, 0.68, '2023-11-22')
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col_date'])
df
```

[image]

And I need to for each group of values from columns: id, col_date (data type datetime) fill values in columns: col1, col2, col3. For each group of values from columns: id, col_date at least one row has values in: col1, col2, col3 and I need to fill rest of rows by this values for each mentioned group.

So, as a result i need to have something like below:

```
data = [
    (1, 9, 0, 0.55, '2023-01-10'),
    (1, 9, 0, 0.55, '2023-01-10'),
    (1, 9, 0, 0.55, '2023-01-10'),
    (2, 88, 1, 0.68, '2023-11-22'),
    (2, 88, 1, 0.68, '2023-11-22')
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col_date'])
df
```

[image]

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas fillna using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391128/pandas-fillna-using-groupby)

Comment: Tranbi, could you show me example code on my example data frame, please ? :)

Comment: In example from you link there is 1 column to fill, in my example there are 3 columns to fill

Comment: Come on, it's right there in the top answer... `df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill()).reset_index(drop=True)` (I just resetted the index)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby_transform` to broadcast the `max` value to all rows of the group (`Nan` will always be smaller than any value). As index is preserved, you can use `fillna` to fill missing values:

```
>>> df.fillna(df.groupby(['id', 'col_date']).transform('max'))

   id  col1  col2  col3   col_date
0   1   9.0   0.0  0.55 2023-01-10
1   1   9.0   0.0  0.55 2023-01-10
2   1   9.0   0.0  0.55 2023-01-10
3   2  88.0   1.0  0.68 2023-11-22
4   2  88.0   1.0  0.68 2023-11-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by 'id' and 'col_date', and fill missing values with the first non-null value in each group with `ffill, bfill`:

**Code:**

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] = df.groupby(['id', 'col_date'])[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill'))
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

**Output:**

```
   id  col1  col2  col3    col_date
0   1   9.0   0.0  0.55  2023-01-10
1   1   9.0   0.0  0.55  2023-01-10
2   1   9.0   0.0  0.55  2023-01-10
3   2  88.0   1.0  0.68  2023-11-22
4   2  88.0   1.0  0.68  2023-11-22
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
df = df[['id', 'col_date']].merge(
        df.dropna(),
        on=['id', 'col_date'], how='left')
```

Output:

```
    col_date    id  col1    col2    col3
0   2023-01-10  1   9.0     0.0    0.55
1   2023-01-10  1   9.0     0.0    0.55
2   2023-01-10  1   9.0     0.0    0.55
3   2023-11-22  2   88.0    1.0    0.68
4   2023-11-22  2   88.0    1.0    0.68
```

Comment: and any other way where you do not refer to 'data'? df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col_date'])