# How to merge observations in one pandas DataFrame where all but one columns are the same?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

So I have this pandas DataFrame, with 5 columns and like 100000 rows. Here's example:

```
    V1      V2          V3          V4  V5
0   2014    Alfa Romeo  159         1   157
1   2014    Alfa Romeo  GIULIETTA   1   119
2   2014    Alfa Romeo  GIULIETTA   3   119
```

What I want to do is to sum values in column V4 IF values in V1, V2, V3 and V5 are exactly the same.

```
    V1      V2          V3          V4  V5
0   2014    Alfa Romeo  159         1   157
1   2014    Alfa Romeo  GIULIETTA   4   119
```

At first I thought that groupby would do the job, but when I did

```
df.groupby(['V1', V2','V3', 'V5' ]).sum()
```

I lost some of the information in column V3, for example, I should have 10 different types of colors but now I have only 3.
How to solve that?

Comment: `lost some of the information in column V3` Can you elaborate?

Comment: Does `df.groupby(['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V5']).V4.sum().reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)` work for you?

Comment: lost some of the information in column V3 Can you elaborate? – cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 
Sure. In my database, I have like 10 types for Volvo (V3 column):
XC60                 
V60                  
V40                  
XC70                 
S60                  
S80                  
V70                  
V40 CROSS COUNTRY    13
XC90                 10
V60 HYBRID            1

and after I make df.groupby(['V1', 'V2', 'V3','V5' ]).agg([ "sum"])
It shows that there's only V70, XC60, XC70, XC90.

Is that a bug in pandas? What do you think?

Comment: df.groupby(['V1', 'V2', 'V3','V5' ],as_index=False).agg([ "sum"])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are dealing with missing data in 'V1','V2','V3' or 'V5' columns and this data is omitted from groupby's.  See this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18431417/6361531)

A workaround is to use fillna():

```
df.fillna("Missing").groupby(['V1','V2','V3','V5']).V4.sum()
```

Example:

print(df)

```
       V1          V2         V3  V4   V5
0  2014.0  Alfa Romeo        159   1  157
1  2014.0  Alfa Romeo  GIULIETTA   1  119
2  2014.0  Alfa Romeo  GIULIETTA   3  119
3     NaN  Alfa Romeo      Black   4  119

df.groupby(['V1','V2','V3','V5']).V4.sum()
```

Missing 'Black':

```
V1      V2          V3         V5 
2014.0  Alfa Romeo  159        157    1
                    GIULIETTA  119    4
Name: V4, dtype: int64
```

Using fillna():

```
df.fillna("Missing").groupby(['V1','V2','V3','V5']).V4.sum()

V1       V2          V3         V5 
2014.0   Alfa Romeo  159        157    1
                     GIULIETTA  119    4
Missing  Alfa Romeo  Black      119    4
Name: V4, dtype: int64
```