# Transform keeping NULLS

Tags: python, pandas, nan, pandas-groupby

I was to use the `transform` method on a `groupby` object using built-in (ie `'mean'`, `'sum`', etc) functions but keep `np.nan` values. For example,

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.random.randint(0,100,8)},index = list('aabbccdd'))
df.iloc[[0,6]] = np.nan

df.groupby(level=0).transform('min')
```

yields

```
   value
a   43.0
a   43.0
b    4.0
b    4.0
c   44.0
c   44.0
d   89.0
d   89.0
```

but i want:

```
   value
a   np.nan
a   np.nan
b    4.0
b    4.0
c   44.0
c   44.0
d   np.nan
d   np.nan
```

Using my own function such as `lambda x: min(skipna=True)` will work...eventually but I have rather millions of small groups on which `lambda` and `numpy` methods takes an eternity. Any suggestions?

Yes, there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values) but note that in that question, the OP wants to include `np.nan` groups whereas I want to not skip over `np.nan` values in the groups

Comment: "NA groups in GroupBy are automatically excluded. This behavior is consistent with R"  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby

Comment: Possible duplicate of [groupby columns with NaN (missing) values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values)

Comment: @xyzjayne please read the question carefully. Your mark of duplication is including `np.nan` groups, my question is not skipping over `np.nan` values in well-defined groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because any recourse within `transform` to `numpy` functions will painfully slow the code down, my workaround is simply to create an additional column that marks nulls and use `transform` and a boolean outside of `transform` to get around the problem:

```
#mark nulls
df.loc[:,'missValue'] = df.value.isnull()

#use min as usual
res = df.groupby(level=0).value.transform('min') 

#mark resulting values as NAN if one of them is missing
res[(df.groupby(level=0).missValue.transform('mean') == .5)] = np.nan
```

The above runs in less than a minute while the code proposed by jpp runs over 10 minutes for one iteration of a subset on my actual data set

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is `NaN`-friendly by default. So you will have to revert to NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.random.randint(0,100,8)}, index=list('aabbccdd'))
df.iloc[[0,6]] = np.nan

res = df.groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: np.min(x.values))

print(res)

   value
a    NaN
a    NaN
b   22.0
b   22.0
c   46.0
c   46.0
d    NaN
d    NaN
```

Alternatively, use `'min'` as normal, and then update where you find null values:

```
res = df.groupby(level=0).transform('min')
res[df.groupby(level=0)['value'].transform(lambda x: x.isnull().any()).astype('bool')] = np.nan
```

Comment: thanks! Alas, it has been 10 min since your answer was posted and the solution code is still running on my real data. I guess I'll have to find a workaround.

Comment: Updated with another solution. Not sure it'll help though if the first solution isn't performant.

Comment: two things: 1) on my version of `Pandas`, `df.groupby(level=0)['value'].transform(lambda x: x.isnull().any())` does not return boolean values (booleans are returned as intergers) so the indexing you proposed does not work. Moreover, the recourse to `lambda` function is no faster than your initial solution. Must say, `transform` works in strange ways

Comment: You can always add `.astype(bool)` to convert integers to Boolean. `transform` confuses me too sometimes.