# aggregation with indices not present in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'y':[7,8,9,10,11,12],'z':['a','a','a','b','b','b']})
i = pd.Index([0,3,5,10,20])
```

The indices in `i` are from a larger dataframe, and `df` is a subset of that larger dataframe. So there will be indices in `i` that will not be in `df`. When I do

```
df.groupby('z').aggregate({'y':lambda x: sum(x.loc[i])}) #I know I can just use .aggregate({'y':sum}), this is just an example to illustrate my problem
```

I get this output

```
   y
z    
a NaN
b NaN
```

as well as a warning message

```
__main__:1: FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
```

How can I avoid this warning message and get the correct output? In my example the only valid indices for `df` are `[0,3,5]` so the expected output is:

```
   y
z    
a  7 #"sum" of index 0 
b  22 #sum of index [3,5]
```

EDIT

The answers here work great but they do not allow different types of aggregation of `x` and `y` columns. For example, let's say I want to sum all elements of `x`, but for `y` only sum the elements in index `i`:

```
df.groupby('z').aggregate({'x':sum, 'y': lambda x: sum(x.loc[i])})
```

this is the desired output:

```
   y   x                       
z    
a  7   6
b  22  15
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael: I have updated my question with the expected output

Comment: Index 5 is not in i.

Comment: `df[df.index.isin(i)].groupby('z')['y'].sum()`

Comment: @ScottBoston: Sorry, you are right. I have updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit for updated question:

```
df.groupby('z').agg({'x':'sum','y':lambda r: r.reindex(i).sum()})
```

Output:

```
    x   y
z        
a   6   7
b  15  22
```

Use `reindex`, to only select those index from i, then `dropna` to remove all those nans from because indexes in i aren't in df.  Then `groupyby` and `agg`:

```
df.reindex(i).dropna(how='all').groupby('z').agg({'y':'sum'})
```

or, you really don't need to dropna:

```
df.reindex(i).groupby('z').agg({'y':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
      y
z      
a   7.0
b  22.0
```

Comment: This is great, thanks, but I don't really understand why this works. `df.reindex(i)` adds a row with `10  NaN   NaN  NaN`, so why doesn't the aggregation return `NaN` as in my original problem?

Comment: Yes, groupby doesn't group on NaN value groups.  However, you could use dropna with how='all' to remove those NaN records as I have shown in the first statement.

Comment: See SO Post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18431417/6361531 about missing values in groupby.

Comment: Thank you for the link. This solution works well, but it won't work for the edited problem in my question... Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) with `df.index` and `i` for get only matched values and then procees data like need:

```
print (df.loc[df.index.intersection(i)])
   x   y  z
0  1   7  a
3  4  10  b
5  6  12  b

df = df.loc[df.index.intersection(i)].groupby('z').agg({'y':'sum'})
#comment alternative
#df = df.loc[df.index.isin(i)].groupby('z').agg({'y':'sum'})
print (df)
    y
z    
a   7
b  22
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = df.groupby('z').aggregate({'x':sum, 'y': lambda x: sum(x.loc[x.index.intersection(i)])})
#comment alternative
#df1 = df.groupby('z').aggregate({'x':sum, 'y': lambda x: sum(x.loc[x.index.isin(i)])})
print (df1)
    x   y
z        
a   6   7
b  15  22
```