# Different behaviour of numpy sum min max functions when aggregating or when applied to list or array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, aggregation

I see different behavior when applying the same numpy function as an aggregation function of groupby or to the same list of values, when nan values are involved.

This applies to np.sum np.min np.max and np.mean
The behavior as aggregation function look the same as if np.nansum, np,nanmin etc are used

For example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
xx = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1.,  2.,      3.],
                   ['A', 3.,  np.nan,  4.],
                   ['B', 5.,  6.,      np.nan],
                   ['B', 7.,  8.,      9.]])

xx.groupby(0).agg(np.sum)
```

Gives

```
       1     2     3
0           
A    4.0   2.0   7.0
B   12.0  14.0   9.0
```

But `np.array([np.nan,9.]).sum()` or
`np.sum(np.array([np.nan,9]))` or
`np.sum([np.nan,9])` they all output `nan`

I would have expected the aggregation function to produce `nan` as well, while the output i got to be generated with the use of `np.nansum`

pandas 0.24.2, numpy  1.16.2

Comment: It seems that rows containing nans are  automatically dropped by groupby. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference comes from pandas behaviour and not `numpy.sum()`.
`np.NaN` are automatically excluded in `pandas.groupby`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
xx = pd.DataFrame([['A', np.nan],
                   ['A', 4.],
                   ['B', 1],
                   ['B', 2]])

xx.groupby(0).count()
```

OUTPUT

```
   1
0   
A  1
B  2
```