# pandas transform with NaN values in grouped columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do some calculations. This works fine:

```
import pandas
import numpy

print(pandas.__version__) #=> 0.25.2

columns = ['CUR', 'ISSUER_INDUSTRY', 'PROFIT']
data = [
    {'CUR': 'NOK', 'ISSUER_INDUSTRY': 'BANK', 'PROFIT': 10},
    {'CUR': 'NOK',  'ISSUER_INDUSTRY': 'BANK', 'PROFIT': 60},
    {'CUR': 'NOK', 'ISSUER_INDUSTRY': 'BANK', 'PROFIT': 80},
    {'CUR': 'SEK', 'ISSUER_INDUSTRY': 'BANK', 'PROFIT': 30},
    {'CUR': 'SEK', 'ISSUER_INDUSTRY': 'TECH', 'PROFIT': 30},
]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

df['above_50_quantile_profit'] = df.PROFIT >= df.groupby(['CUR','ISSUER_INDUSTRY']).PROFIT.transform('quantile')

df['above_90_quantile_profit'] = df.PROFIT >= df.groupby(['CUR','ISSUER_INDUSTRY']).PROFIT.transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.9))
```

The DF now looks like

```
NOK     BANK    10  False   False
NOK     BANK    60  True    False
NOK     BANK    80  True    True
SEK     BANK    30  True    True
SEK     TECH    30  True    True
```

But in reality data is never this clean. So I have some rows that are missing industry data:

```
df.loc[df.CUR=='SEK','ISSUER_INDUSTRY'] = numpy.nan
```

Now my first calculation works fine:

```
df['above_50_quantile_profit'] = df.PROFIT >= df.groupby(['CUR','ISSUER_INDUSTRY']).PROFIT.transform('quantile')
```

but my second:

```
df['above_90_quantile_profit'] = df.PROFIT >= df.groupby(['CUR','ISSUER_INDUSTRY']).PROFIT.transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.9))
```

now raised:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 5 elements
```

I understand that grouping on NaN is a well know problem ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values)), what I do not understand is why the first version `.transform('quantile')` have the same problem, as it is also a groupby call.

Could anyone help me understand the difference?

Comment: There is problem if NaNs then rows are removed by design, so added link for solution.

Comment: A simple way to deal with this problem would be a conversion to `Int64`.

So you could implement this: `df['above_90_quantile_profit'] = df.PROFIT >= df.groupby(['CUR','ISSUER_INDUSTRY']).PROFIT.transform(lambda x: x.astype("Int64").quantile(0.9))`