# Looping over Pandas' groupby output when grouping by multiple columns and missing data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Grouping by multiple columns with missing data:

```
data = [['Falcon', 'Captive', 390], ['Falcon', None, 350],
        ['Parrot', 'Captive', 30], ['Parrot', 'Wild', 20]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Animal', 'Type', 'Max Speed'])
```

I understand how missing data are dealt with when grouping by individual columns ([groupby columns with NaN (missing) values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values)), but do not understand the behaviour when grouping by two columns.

It seems I cannot loop over all groups even though they seem to identified:

```
groupeddf = df.groupby(['Animal', 'Type'])
counter = 0
for group in groupeddf:
    counter = counter + 1
print(counter)
len(groupeddf.groups)
```

results in 3 and 4 which is not consistent.

Pandas version 1.0.3

Comment: Yes but if you do `for group in groupeddf.groups` you get 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post concerning *groupby columns with NaN (missing) values*
there is a sentence: *NA groups in GroupBy are automatically excluded*.

Apparently, in case of grouping by **multiple** columns, the same
occurs if **any level** of grouping key contains *NaN*.

To confirm it, run:

```
for key, grp in groupeddf:
    print(f'\nGroup: {key}\n{grp}')
```

and the result will be:

```
Group: ('Falcon', 'Captive')
   Animal     Type  Max Speed
0  Falcon  Captive        390

Group: ('Parrot', 'Captive')
   Animal     Type  Max Speed
2  Parrot  Captive         30

Group: ('Parrot', 'Wild')
   Animal  Type  Max Speed
3  Parrot  Wild         20
```

But if you execute *groupeddf.groups* (to print the content), you will get:

```
{('Falcon', 'Captive'): Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'),
 ('Falcon', nan): Int64Index([1], dtype='int64'),
 ('Parrot', 'Captive'): Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'),
 ('Parrot', 'Wild'): Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')}
```

So we have group *('Falcon', nan)*, containing row with index *1*.

If you want to process **all** groups, without any tricks to change
*NaN* into something other, run something like:

```
for key in groupeddf.groups:
    print(f'\nGroup: {key}\n{df.loc[groupeddf.groups[key]]}')
```

This time the printout will contain also the previously missing group.

Comment: So, it is excluded, but not really excluded? I understand the workaround(s), but not the DataFrameGroupBy object.

Comment: The above exclusion pertains only to how "iterator access" (*for* loop) works on the *GrouBy* object itself. As I just found, it does **not** pertain to iterator access to *GrouBy.groups*.

Answer (score 1):

To loop over all groups in pandas 1.0 you'll need to convert the `NoneType` objects to strings.

```
df = df.astype(str) # or just df['Type'] = df['Type'].astype(str)
```

Then you'll get four iterations of your loop.

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#groupby-missing):

> **NA and NaT group handling**
>
> If there are any NaN or NaT values in the
>   grouping key, these will be automatically excluded. In other words,
>   there will never be an “NA group” or “NaT group”. This was not the
>   case in older versions of pandas, but users were generally discarding
>   the NA group anyway (and supporting it was an implementation
>   headache).

Or you could upgrade to the dev pandas 1.1, where [this issue appears to be fixed with the option `dropna=False`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#allow-na-in-groupby-key)