# Merge rows of the same dataframe by columns

Tags: python, pandas, row

I am new to Python and i can solve the following problem.
I have a dataframe that looks like that:

```
ID      X1     x2     x3
1       15     NaN    NaN
2       NaN    2      NaN
3       NaN    NaN    5
1       NaN    16     NaN
2       1      NaN    NaN
3       6      NaN    NaN
4       NaN    NaN    75
5       NaN    67     NaN
```

I want to merge the rows by ID, as a result it should look like that:

```
ID    x1    x2   x3
1     15    16   NaN
2     1     2    NaN
3     6     NaN  5
4     NaN   NaN  75
5     NaN   67   NaN
```

I have tryed a lot with `df.groupby("ID")`, without success.
Can someone fix that for me an supply the code for me. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your existing `groupby` like this. You can remove `replace` part if you would like `0.0` instead of `NaN`:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.fillna(0).astype(int).groupby('ID').sum().replace(0,np.nan)
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
      
ID    X1    x2    x3
1   15.0  16.0   NaN
2    1.0   2.0   NaN
3    6.0   NaN   5.0
4    NaN   NaN  75.0
5    NaN  67.0   NaN
```

If you don't want `ID` as index, you can  add `reset_index`:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.fillna(0).astype(int).groupby('ID').sum().replace(0,np.nan).reset_index()
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
   ID    X1    x2    x3
0   1  15.0  16.0   NaN
1   2   1.0   2.0   NaN
2   3   6.0   NaN   5.0
3   4   NaN   NaN  75.0
4   5   NaN  67.0   NaN
```

Comment: it works, thank you very much! But all the ID´s (not shown) with value NaN in x1 will be deleted, that should not be happening. Do you also have a solution for that, @Grayrigel?

Comment: Can you share the real input data?

Comment: @Grayrigel - use this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/pandas-groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values

Comment: No sadly not, but i edited the question. Now it should be clearer. Sorry it was my mistake.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it. I thought of using `sum` . However, OP wanted to keep `NaN` so, couldn't thing anything than replacing `0.0` with `NaN`.

Comment: @Tobi_93 Please Check the updated answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Grayrigel, thanks for the update. No, x1 will be deleted or not shown then. ID x2 and x3 is still there.

Comment: @Tobi_93  Can you try now? Hopefully this should resolve the problem.

Comment: The ID column is alwas filled with data, so there are no missing ones, just duplicates, @jezrael. Grayrigel, i have tried it, still the same issue. Sorry, thanks for you help but do not spend to much time on it.

Comment: @Grayrigel i found out that x1 is in the orginal data dtype = object, i think thats why the sum() is not working.

Comment: @Tobi_93 Updated my answer once more. This convert x1 dtype to int. It should work now. If it doesn't work can you check the initial `fillna` is working or not.

Comment: Great, thats the solution! Thank you very much for your effort! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID',as_index=False,sort=False).last()
```