# pandas group by with nan

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan

pandas seems to simply drop columns with NaN in group by.    I want to get "NaN",0, or some other value if there is a NaN in the grouping.   I have numbers of columns that I am summing.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `.fillna(...)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas GroupBy columns with NaN (missing) values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/pandas-groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values)