# Column increment counter and reset based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column that counts incrementally as it goes down the rows group by one column and based on yet another column.

Additionaly if one of the status is blank (as in an empty string) it would be ignored and repeat the count for that blank from the previous one.

So I have this data

```
      car  status  
0    audi   False      
1    audi   False      
2    audi   False      
3    audi    True      
4     bmw   False     
5     bmw   ''      
6     bmw   False      
7     bmw    True      
8     bmw   False      
9   lexus    True      
10  lexus    True      
11  lexus    True
```

I would like to add a colum that counts how many consecutive `False` are in status as it goes counting for each `car` and reset when there is a `True` to start again if there is another `False` or another `car`

```
      car  status  counter
0    audi   False  1
1    audi   False  2   
2    audi   False  3   
3    audi    True  0   
4     bmw   False  1   
5     bmw   ''     1 
5     bmw   False  2    
6     bmw    True  0    
7     bmw   False  1         
9   lexus    True  0
10  lexus    True  0   
11  lexus   False  1
```

I am trying this but it increments by car

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['audi', False],
        ['audi', False],
        ['audi', False],
        ['audi', True],
        ['bmw', False],
        ['bmw', False],
        ['bmw', False],
        ['bmw', True],
        ['bmw', False],
        ['lexus', True],
        ['lexus', True],
        ['lexus', False]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['car', 'status'])

df['count'] = df.groupby('car')['status'].transform(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum())

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with grouping consecutive values, last set `0` for `status=True` values by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
s = df['status'].eq(True)
df['count'] = (df.groupby(['car', s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()])
                 .cumcount()
                 .add(1)
                 .mask(df['status'], 0))

print(df)
      car  status  count
0    audi   False      1
1    audi   False      2
2    audi   False      3
3    audi    True      0
4     bmw   False      1
5     bmw   False      2
6     bmw   False      3
7     bmw    True      0
8     bmw   False      1
9   lexus    True      0
10  lexus    True      0
11  lexus   False      1
```

Alternative solution, for working with boolean column only:

```
s = df['status'].eq(True)
df['count'] = (df.groupby(['car', (~s & s.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum()])
                 .cumcount()
                 .add(1)
                 .mask(df['status'], 0))
```

EDIT:

```
data = [['audi', False],        
        ['audi', False],         
        ['bmw', False],        
        ['bmw', False],        
        ['bmw', ''],         
        ['bmw', ''],         
        ['bmw', False],         
        ['bmw', True],         
        ['bmw', False],         
        ['lexus', True],         
        ['lexus', True],         
        ['lexus', False]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['car', 'status'])
```

---

```
m = df['status'].isin([True, False])
df1 = df[m].copy()
df.loc[m, 'count'] = (df1.groupby(['car', df1['status'].ne(df1['status'].shift()).cumsum()])
                        .cumcount())

df['count'] = df.groupby('car')['count'].bfill().fillna(0).astype('int')
print(df)
      car status  count
0    audi  False      0
1    audi  False      1
2     bmw  False      0
3     bmw  False      1
4     bmw             2
5     bmw             2
6     bmw  False      2
7     bmw   True      0
8     bmw  False      0
9   lexus   True      0
10  lexus   True      1
11  lexus  False      0
```

Comment: What happens when there is an empty status, say an empty string? I would like to ignore it, but both solutions would error as it expects a boolean

Comment: @Álvaro - [depends of pandas version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/pandas-groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values), what is your pandas version?

Comment: Latests version

Comment: @Álvaro - if empty string `''` all working correct.

Comment: If need set `NaN` if starting `''` then use `df['count'] = df.groupby('car')['count'].bfill().astype('Int64')`

Comment: It should be `0` for `NaN` just because there is no previous 'amount', `1` for `False` as an increment and back to `0` for `True` as a reset

Comment: @Álvaro - Understand, then need `df['count'] = df.groupby('car')['count'].bfill().fillna(0).astype('int')`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244246/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-column-increment-counter-and-reset-based-on-othe).